# How to resolve the socket timeout error on my webserver

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

**Background:** I have four webserver with LAMP under my AWS ELB. Each webserver has two virtual host on these servers. 
**Issue:** I am continuously getting site down alert from pingdom with below error

```
Socket timeout, unable to connect to server
```

At ELB level there are no issues. My instances also has around 10GB of free memory available at this moment but still I am getting site down alert from pingdom. How could I get my application running without any issues. Does changing the below TCP timeout values help

```
tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75
tcp_keepalive_probes = 9
```